# XPutImage to a DefaultRootWindow() gives nothing

Tags: x11, xlib, xorg

I'm trying to write a screensaver compatible to the "xscreensaver"-package.
This requires the program to draw something in a root-window.
My program runs fine when I create a non-root-window myself, e.g.:

```
Window window = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, RootWindow(display, 0), 0, 0, width, height, 1, 0, 0);
```

drawing it to a

Window window = DefaultRootWindow(display);

instead gives nothing.
I tried running it from xscreensaver-demo, from an xterm, from an environment without window manager but all they give is black.
In the terminal from where I start it, no X11 errors are shown.
Also my error-handler is not triggered.
I guess my biggest problem now is that I can't find (not even with google) how to debug something like this.

Any help is appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

void draw(char *rgb_out, int w, int h)
{
        for(int i=0; i<w*h*4; i++)
                *rgb_out++ = rand();
}

XImage *create_ximage(Display *display, Visual *visual, int width, int height)
{
        char *image32 = (char *)malloc(width * height * 4);
        draw(image32, width, height);
        return XCreateImage(display, visual, 24, ZPixmap, 0, image32, width, height, 32, 0);
}

int x11_err_handler(Display *pd, XErrorEvent *pxev)
{
        char msg[4096] = { 0 };
        XGetErrorText(pd, pxev -> error_code, msg, sizeof(msg));
        printf("%s\n", msg);
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        Display *display = XOpenDisplay(getenv("DISPLAY"));

        Window window = DefaultRootWindow(display);

        XWindowAttributes wa;
        XGetWindowAttributes(display, window, &wa);
        int width = wa.width, height = wa.height;
        printf("res: %dx%d\n", width, height);

        GC gc = XCreateGC(display, window, 0, NULL);
        Visual *visual = DefaultVisual(display, 0);

        XSetErrorHandler(x11_err_handler);

        for(;;)
        {
                XImage *ximage = create_ximage(display, visual, width, height);
                XPutImage(display, window, gc, ximage, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);
                XDestroyImage(ximage);

                XFlush(display);

                usleep(50000);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

It can be compiled using:

```
g++ -O3 -lX11 -lXpm so.cpp
```

Comment: Are you sure your root window is visible (not obscured by other window?) Try 'xwininfo -tree' and click on desktop. Also, why do you want to draw on root? Just create window size of a screen with override redirect flag

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me, tested with Xephyr. My guess (as I already commented) that in your setup root window is obscured by DE, for example in ubuntu there could be 'nautilus' running full screen to provide desktop / icons / DnD / rubber band selection functionality.

Comment: The xscreensaver package requires you to write on the root. I also tested it without any other window obscuring it: without any window manager and only xterm. Also running it from within xscreenaver-demo does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Xscreensaver does not require you to draw on the root window, in fact, this will not work. Xscreensaver creates a "virtual root" and programs that are "virtual root aware" will treat this virtual root window as the root window (it is not the root window). Your best bet is to check the environment variables which Xscreensaver sets (XSCREENSAVER_WINDOW) to find the window ID of the virtual root and draw to that.